# Want to update Date time by setting the hours, minutes, and seconds on React using Date class

Tags: reactjs, date, setter

So I'm trying to update the Hour, minutes, and seconds values through a prompt when I click on the header but I am unable to do so. Could any one help?

I have tried using the setters from the Date class, but no luck. I believe it has something do to with the componentWillMount() but I am not sure how to go about solving it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'



class Clock extends Component {

  constructor()
  {
       super()
       this.state = {time:new Date()}
  }
 
 componentWillMount(){
      setInterval(() => this.setState({time:new Date()}),1000)
      //setInterval(() => this.state.time.setSeconds(1),1000);
       
  }

  setHour(){
   // alert("This is the hour");  
     let hour = prompt("Enter the hour you would like to change to" , 12);

       //! Not working
     this.state.time.setHours(hour);

  }

  setMinutes(){
     //alert("This is the minutes");       
     let minutes = prompt("Enter the minutes you would like to change to" , 30);

       //! Not working
     this.state.time.setHours(minutes);
  }

  setSeconds(){
     //alert("This is the seconds");     
     let seconds = prompt("Enter the seconds you would like to change to" , 35);

     //! Not working
     this.state.time.setHours(seconds);
      
  }
  
     render() {
    return (
      <div style={{border: '5px solid black', textAlign: 'center', width: '30%',}}>
           
           
           <h4 style={{margin: '10px'}} >London Clock  </h4>
           <h4  onClick={this.setHour} style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString().slice(0,1)} : </h4>
           <h4  onClick={this.setMinutes} style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString().slice(2,4)} : </h4>
           <h4  onClick={this.setSeconds} style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString().slice(5,8)}</h4>
           <h4  style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString().slice(8,10)}</h4>

           {/* Just to take care of the bottom margin of the border */}
           <h1 style={{margin: '10px'}}></h1>
           
           
     </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Clock
```

[Here is the visual of my Clock Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q39fg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.setHours(hour)` does not notify React that the state has changed as the function call is mutating the data members of the Date class and React has no idea about the change. To fix this you have two options:

1. After the call to `.setHours(hour)` call `this.setState({time: this.state.time})`. The setState function should notify react that something changed.
2. Do something like 
   `let time = this.state.time; time.setHours(hour); this.setState({time: time});`

Edit: You might want to bind this in the onClick functions like 
 `onClick={this.setHour.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on react functional component then,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const DateTime = () => {
  var [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    var timer = setInterval(() => setDate(new Date()), 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p> Time : {date.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
      <p> Date : {date.toLocaleDateString()}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateTime;
```